# Redirection "www" to "http://" of a Wordpress site by .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I'm having a problem displaying my Wordpress site with the "www." prefix.

Indeed, when I access it via http://" the homepage is displayed normally, and when I add the prefix "www." it seems that the redirection fails and displays the contents of the directory at the root of the site :

[image: homepage www]

So I wanted to modify the default .htaccess of my Wordpress website :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

By adding this redirect rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.herefor.digital
RewriteRule (.*) http://herefor.digital/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I don't know where to add the "www." to "http://". This crashes the site.

Yes should I according to add it, and is the procedure/syntax good on its own?

My website link : http://herefor.digital

Thanks a lot

Comment: That looks like you dont have both domains pointing to the same folder to begin with ... The www-less version apparently points to the `www` folder, whereas the version _with_ `www` does not ...?

Comment: @CBroe Hello, are you talking about DNS?

Comment: No, about the VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, you were right! My "www" host was pointing to "./" instead of the "./www" directory. So I updated this via my host interface and after a few minutes, it now works! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the crash of your site when you implement the redirect. Within the WordPress Admin navigate to Settings -> General. From there make sure the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" is set to use https://www. and click Save Changes at the bottom.

Comment: Hello, I put: http:// herefor.digital (without space) for the two fields: Wordpress URL & web URL

Answer (score 0):

Ok @CBroe found the source of the problem.
My "www" host was pointing to "./" instead of the "./www" directory. So I updated this via my host interface and after a few minutes, it now works!

Thanks a lot ;)